# Magic item to create juju zombies?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, magic-items, undead

I would like to create juju zombies by using an item.  Are there any stock magic items that can do this, for example by allowing the user to create undead as the spell [Create Undead](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/c/create-undead)?  I can't create a custom magic item that simply performs a Create Undead because my GM doesn't allow that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [Sword of Gluttony, Ungarato](http://archivesofnethys.com/MagicArtifactsDisplay.aspx?ItemName=Sword%20of%20Gluttony,%20Ungarato) will turn slain foes into [Juju Zombies](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/bestiary/monster-listings/templates/zombie-juju-cr-1), automaticaly under the control of the wielder.

> Any creature slain by Ungarato—either as the effect of a critical hit or otherwise—reanimates as a juju zombie (see Bestiary 2) 1d4 rounds later under the control of the sword wielder. The sword can control up to 32 HD worth of juju zombies in this way. If this amount is exceeded, undead are released from control as per animate dead.

[Ungarato](http://archivesofnethys.com/MagicArtifactsDisplay.aspx?ItemName=Sword%20of%20Gluttony,%20Ungarato) is one of the [Seven Swords of Sin](http://pathfinderwiki.com/wiki/Alara'hai).

So, its neither a stock item, nor readily available. But i had to mention it.

Comment: This is something exactly what I am looking for, a magical item that lets you create juju zombies. Thank your for the answer.
P.S. I didn't notice that the word stock item is now in there, I'll have to check that out

Answer (score 6):

## Creating [juju zombies](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/bestiary/monster-listings/templates/zombie-juju-cr-1)

The spell [*create undead*](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/c/create-undead) when employed by a level 11 caster can create juju zombies. Hence, a staff or a scroll of that spell is the easiest magic item that allows juju zombie creation.

Other than that, the [*onyx spear*](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic-items/magic-weapons/specific-magic-weapons/onyx-spear) (né the *Wendifisa spear* from [*Inner Sea Combat*](http://paizo.com/products/btpy95b1?Pathfinder-Campaign-Setting-Inner-Sea-Combat)) animates the wielder as a juju zombie if the *spear*'s linked onyx is within 100 ft. of the wielder upon the wielder's death. A creature that distributes such *spears* to his future juju zombies must have his own way of commanding the resultant juju zombies as they are free-willed upon their animation.

Comment: I was under the impression that only juju oracles are capable of creating juju zombies with a special version of create undead which they gain as a 5th level spell

Comment: @Fering I'm just going by d20PFSRD says here. That's what the links tell me.

Comment: Fair enough, there is nothing listed in the notes at the bottom which says otherwise